# .DS_Store is not a directory error - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on an Android project from my Macbook and I'm getting the error

```
'/Users/myname/Desktop/AndroidLabs2/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/.DS_Store' is not a directory
```

I've added it to my .gitignore and to under Preferences>File Types>Ignored Files and Folders and yet when I run my project I'm still getting the same error.

I know that .DS_Store is something that IOS automatically adds when you view the files through the Finder (From my understanding) but I really just need to get this to run.

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and coding in general so this could very well be an extremely simple fix but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

i had same error when try Generate Signed APK on release mode
For me Clean Project and Rebuild Project and error gone!